# Install driver form command line

Tags: boot, command-line, drivers, nvidia, gui

I recently did some stuff on my computer (installing various things) and now my computer does not have a GUI. I can log into my computer via command line and work only from the command line. I need drivers for my computer. I am not sure how to install them. I  tried this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

but that throws many errors. How can I install the latest stable proprietary driver? This has to be done form the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way should be:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now, run:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

to find out recommended Nvidia driver for your machine. If this is let's say, for example, `nvidia-319`, then, to install it, run:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

This should be enough.

More about: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers).